# SSH 'command not found' when trying to connect to AWS

Tags: ssh, amazon-web-services, terminal, openssh

I'm new to Amazon web services and have managed to set up an instance.
I already have the ssh directory on my machine at: /usr/bin/ssh

I have also downloaded a Pem key file to my machine and have tried to copy my Pem key file into that directory but I cannot navigate to it. When I try:

```
cd /usr/bin/ssh
```

I get:

```
-bash: cd: /usr/bin/ssh: Not a directory
```

When I just try to type the command:

```
ssh
```

I get the following:

```
BEGIN: command not found
: command not found2: MIIEpAIBAAKCAQEAu6JORnapcVdvAwPm+6LVBA3n8chlGU4nE0g9nyD8zSDWlATJpf1Td35tPrxj
: No such file or directory
```

can anyone help with this?

I'm on OSX Lion 10.8.4 if that helps!

Answer (score 0):

Your problem appears to be related to configuring the ssh keys.  First, some clarifications:

- /usr/bin/ssh is not a directory, it is the actual secure shell program.  Do not modify it. (If you have already destroyed your ssh installation, you would need to restore the installation: http://support.apple.com/kb/PH10763).
- ssh will use a public and a private key (keypair) to authenticate.  The private key should be stored locally on your computer, generally in the .ssh folder inside your home directory (~/.ssh)
- You may have generated the keypair yourself, or have gotten one generated by AWS.

I will assume your .pem file is the private key portion of the keypair, and that you have downloaded that from AWS after following a procedure along the lines of: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/how-to-have-aws-create-the-key-pair-for-you.html.

In that case, you need to simply:

- copy the .pem file into your ~/.ssh directory.
- rename it to id_rsa
- ensure that you have correctly set permissions for the private key and .ssh directory (ssh is picky), typically 600 for the id_rsa file and 700 for the .ssh directory.
- initiate the ssh connection via `ssh username@host`

Comment: THanks for taking the time with your response -  i think i may have copied my .pem file onto the /usr/bin/ssh - so tried to copy it back from another mac and now when I run:/usr/bin/ssh -v I get:
dyld: Library not loaded: /usr/lib/libwrap.7.dylib
  Referenced from: /usr/bin/ssh
  Reason: image not found
Trace/BPT trap: 5

Comment: It sounds like you broke your ssh executable. Not sure how to reinstall it since its installed by default with OSX.

Comment: Yes, at this point, you should go for system restore: http://support.apple.com/kb/PH10763 (modified the answer inline).